# Word count program in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count the number of times each word occurs in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103927/count-the-number-of-times-each-word-occurs-in-a-file)

Hi,
Its been a long time since I did my C++ programming.
This could be quite a dumb question.
I have found several programs on word count in this site.
But most of them are using `std::string` as their keys.
In my case, I needed to use `char*` as my key.
But it seems since each `char*` has different address values, the duplicate keys are getting inserted in my map.

```
char str[] = "This This";
typedef std::map<char*, int> word_count_t;
typedef word_count_t::iterator word_count_iter_t;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    word_count_t word_count;
    word_count_iter_t itr = NULL;

    while(token) {
        ++word_count[token];
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for(itr = word_count.begin(); itr != word_count.end(); itr++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << itr->first  << ", Value: " << itr->second << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

The output I m getting for this program is

> Key: This, Value: 1
>   Key: This, Value: 1

I wanted output like

> Key: This, Value: 2

Can somebody tell me where did I miss what?

Thanks.

Comment: A Map cannot have duplicate keys, You should use multimap.

Comment: @Als He doesn't want duplicate keys.

Comment: @Nawaz Except that he isn't counting words from a file.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `std::map<std::string, int>` - your map of `char*` will be comparing pointers not the strings they point to.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` by default uses `operator <` on the key type for doing comparisons. `operator <` on `char *` compares *pointer addresses*, not the characters of the strings.

You want to use `std::map<std::string, int>` instead, as `operator <` on `std::string` does lexical string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You must make your own compare class for `const char *`:

```
struct StrCmp {
    static bool operator() (const char *a, const char *b) {
        return strcmp(a, b)<0;
    }
};
```

Then you can use a map:

```
typedef std::map<char const *, int, StrCmp> word_count_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really use some HashMap implementation. std::map is a TreeMap and will be slower when counting words in a huge text. This is due to the fact, that huge amounts of word occurrences in the text will be mapped to a moderate amount of distinct words. Even if you require the output to be sorted, sorting a hashmap afterwards can be better, because inserting into the tree will be #occurrences * log #words while sorting them will be O(#words * log #words)

Apart from that, most hashmap implementations (personally i'm usually using google::dense_hash_map or google::sparse_hash_map) can deal with char* without you having to write a hash function (they use an stl hash function). So it's basically plug & play for you.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are different because they are `char*`, that is, pointers pointing to a different position in memory. If you used an `std::map<std::string, int>` and you did a `++word_count[std::string(token)]` you would get the expected output.