# Counting # of words in a line

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying to do, this is not nearly the entire program I am making just a small portion. This part is counting the # of words of what I enter.

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '.')
    {
        numWords++;
    }
}
```

This obviously works if someone enters a correct line with a period at the end. I can't think of how to get it to recognize the end of line character though, incase they don't put a period.

Comment: how about newline -- \n character ?  Also, I'm pretty sure there are standard input processing functions (its been a while for me with C++ or C# etc) for handling newlines.  And lastly - a period is a terrible signifier for the end of a line, for example what if the input contained two sentences?

Comment: that doesn't count the last word then though. if i input "hello" it will tell me 0 words

Comment: Nah I want to know the total amount of words in the input.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? It seems that you are able to count number of words just by looking at number of spaces entered. Then at the end just add 1 to the total. Ex: `What is wrong with the code you have?` using your code, I get 7 + 1 = 8

Comment: "Hello Dr. Smith.  It's nice to meet you."  8 words, or 11?

Comment: ah thanks @Smac89. I didn't think of that because it wouldn't work if there was no words entered. But by checking if !s.empty() I can only add 1 if there is something in the string.

Comment: This way it will only works if words are seperated by **exactly** 1 space or dot. So you cannot count words like this. Better jumps over continuous spaces

Answer (score 0):

Why not just start the numWords counter on 1 and only count the spaces?

Comment: Cuz if I don't enter anything, it will say there is 1 word.

Comment: See this on string explosion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448176/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-c  you could use this to explode the words and then check the sizeof the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the number of " " in your line and add that to `1`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  bool previousSpace = false;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
    if (isspace(s[i]) || s[i] == '.')
    {
        if (previousSpace == false)
        {
          numWords++;
          previousSpace = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      previousSpace = false;
    }
  }
  cout << numWords + (previousSpace ? 0 : 1) << endl;
```

This considers more than one consecutive spaces. The key here is to use `isspace` function.

Answer (score -1):

Could this be the same that you are after? [Count the number of times each word occurs in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103927/count-the-number-of-times-each-word-occurs-in-a-file) or this already duplicate one [Word count program in C++ duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135698/word-count-program-in-c)?