# How to count string occurence in string in C++

Tags: c++, c

Example 
   I have inputted  "he he she she she "
        output    " he  2
                     she 3 "

Comment: and what were your efforts until now?

Comment: what @x13n said, plus you're a bit unclear, do you want a word count of everything in the string, do you want a count of specific words, do you want a count of directly repeated words/substrings, ...

Comment: C and C++ are not the same. Tag with the one you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of times each word occurs in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103927/count-the-number-of-times-each-word-occurs-in-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a std::map. Since the value of a non-existing key is inserted implicitly with the default value (0 for unsigned) when calling the []-operator, you could tokenize the string and then do the following:

```
++map[token];
```

Afterwards you have a map of strings and each entry has a pair of a string (which is a token you parsed before) and an unsigned int indicating how often the token occurred.

Comment: Integers don't have a defined default value (at least not before C++11, for that one that I'm not sure). And I'm quite sure you can't default-construct a non-existing map key to read from (which preincrement needs).

Comment: The map's operator[] actually does that, even if it is a bit odd. If the value doesn't exist, a default value is inserted (using 0 for ints). The operator then returns a reference to the entry.

Comment: @Bo Persson: nice, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I writed from memory without testing.
It should return number of all words withing your string.
This is not doing exacly what you need. But you need to think by yourself a little bit.
It is easy to implement some kind of collection that would hold your own structs (string + number of occurenced).

```
INT GetStringsNumber(char *szInput)
{
    INT iReturn = 0;
    INT iSize = strlen(szInput) - 1;
    for(INT i = 0; i <= iSize; i++)
    {
        if(szInput[i] == ' ')
        {
            if(i < iSize && szInput[i+1] != ' ')
            {
                iReturn++;
            }
        }
    }
    return iReturn;
}
```