# Counting occurrences of words in a string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to create a dictionary that reads a file into a string vector and counts the number of times each unique word occurs. Here's what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream input1;
    input1.open("Base_text.txt");

    vector<string> base_file;
    vector<int> base_count;


    if (input1.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Input file 1 opening failed."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    make_dictionary(input1, base_file, base_count);


}

void make_dictionary(istream& file, vector<string>& words, vector<int>& count)
{


    string word;
    int i=0;

    while (file>>word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
        cout<<words[i];
        i++;
    }


    for (i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((words[i+1]!=words[i]))
            {
                count.push_back(i);

            }
    }
```

Question 1: How do I get the vector to include spaces and recognize individual words?
Question 2: Any ideas how to proceed with the second part (for loop)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of times each word occurs in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103927/count-the-number-of-times-each-word-occurs-in-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

This is quite inefficient. You should use

```
 std::map<string, int>
```

instead. It is both easier and more efficient.

Loop over the file. When you see a word, see if it's in the map. If it's not, add a new word with count 1. If it is, increment the count.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be that complicated `std::map<string, int> dict; ... ++dict[word];` is all you need.

Comment: Not sure if the int value will be initialized to 0 when operator[] inserts a new element, though.

Comment: It will, it's guaranteed, don't ask me to quote the standard however.